# Equation from a given sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm seeing a sequence of numbers:

$$0,1,5,11,17,25,33,43,53,65,77,91,
105,121,137,155,173,193,213,235,257
...$$
And I'm searching for its equation, I'm not into maths, so   forgive me   if    it's simple... I found one:

$$-11-(-1)^n+12n+2n^2\over4$$

But I found it utterly complex for a sequence that look "smooth" when plotted, also, when plotting the equation, [it giggles](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-11+-+%28-1%29+**+n+%2B+12+*+n+%2B+2+*+n+**+2%29+%2F+4&dataset=), that make me think it's "too complex" for what I'm asking.

So how do we cleanly infer an equation from a sequence ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with the hammer I had and after some hour of CPU I found an equation.

Sadly the equation is off by 0.5 one other value, so I have to cast the result to an integer to drop the error ^-^. That probably why my first equation was jittering.

New equation is:

`0.5 * (x + 3) ^ 2 - 7`

Answer (score 2):

This question (with different numbers) just keeps popping up every now and then. Long story short, it is possible to produce a formula, and you just did that. The general problem (to infer an equation from a sequence), however, can't be solved, and not because there is no way, but because there are too many ways. There are many equations for any given set of numbers, and all those equations would exactly reproduce your numbers, and then would diverge and follow utterly different paths.

Also, there is nothing wrong with complex-looking equation producing smooth results.

Comment: :( I'm actually trying to converge to another via a genetic algorithm, varying [a, b, c, d] on a `a + x * b + (x ^ 2 * c) / d`, using the same technique, is there a "probably better" equation I can use ? As the genetic algorithm can easily converte to put 0 on unnecessary items, we may add anything...

Comment: When you have a hammer, every problem looks like a nail, they say :) Why use genetic algorithm, when you may easily arrive at analytical [least-squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) approximation? Why use c and d, when you actually divide one by the other? Your initial formula is probably the best in some sense, although it may be hard to specify exactly what sense is it.

Comment: I also tried with least squares using numpy, and I'm confident throwing genetic at it won't solve it. Yet its entertaining, like using a hammer to trigger explosives ;)